# How to retrieve the users email address from google+ using AWS Cognito in iOS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, swift3, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-ios

I am using AWS Cognito to authenticate an iOS app into AWS Mobile Hub using google+. The authentication works fine, but I am struggling to find a way to retrieve the email address from its google+ account. I can easily get the user name and its Cognito ID, but is it possible to get the email address?
In MS Azure I can do it but in the server side.
This is my code in Swift 3.0:

```
    AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().loginWithSign(signInProvider!, completionHandler: {(result: Any?, error: Error?) in
      if error == nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                print(AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().userName)
                print("-------------")
                print(result)
      }
    })
```

Comment: As of now no way to get the user `email id` using mobile hub.

Comment: Thank you for the answer